# trying to prove the following convergence result

Tags: calculus

So, this is propably some standard result from integral calculus:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$,  $f \geq 0$ such that

$\int^\infty_0 f < \infty$,
and

$|\frac{d}{dx} f| \leq C$ for all x some constant C.
Then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

I got nowhere with mean value theorems, and i just cant seem to find it. can anyone help?

thanks.

Comment: Are you assuming the limit of the integral exists and is finite?

Comment: yes thats what i was trying to say with $\int^\infty_0 f < \infty$. a bit sloppy : )

Answer (score 1):

Let $\let\epsilon\varepsilon\epsilon>0$ and assume there is a sequence  $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$  with $f(x_n)\ge \epsilon$ and $x_n\to \infty$. Show that $\int_{x_n-\frac\epsilon C}^{x_n+\frac\epsilon C}f(t)\,\mathrm dt>\frac{\epsilon^2}C$.
We may assume wlog. that $x_{n+1}>x_n+\frac{2\epsilon}C$ and conlude $\int_0^{x_n} f(t)\,\mathrm dt\ge n\cdot\frac{\epsilon^3} C\to\infty$.

Comment: Technically the assumption should be $|f(x_n)| \geq \epsilon$, and then WLOG you can assume it's always positive or always negative because one of these must happen infinitely often and the cases are treated essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $|f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ holds for some $\epsilon > 0$ for infinitely many arbitrarily large $x$, then choose an increasing subsequence $x_n$ of such $x$ that are at least some constant distance away from each other, e.g. $x_{n+1} - x_n > 1$. Then since the derivative of $f$ is bounded, you will be able to lower bound the absolute value of a contribution to the integral centered at $x_n$, over some fixed length interval centered there. As a further hint, take your intervals to be $[x_n - x_0, x_n + x_0]$ for some fixed positive $x_0$ where $x_0 < 1/2$ and $x_n < \epsilon / C$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\lim_{M \to \infty} \int_M^\infty f = 0$, and
$f(x) \ge f(x_0) - C |x-x_0|$

If $f(x_0) >0$, then the set $\{x | f(x)\ge 0 \}$ contains the set
$[x_0-{ f(x_0)\over C}, x_0+{ f(x_0)\over C}]$ and so
$\int_{x_0}^\infty f \ge { f(x_0)\over C} f(x_0)$. It is easy to see that this holds for all $x_0$, hence we see that $f(x_0) \to 0 $.